# My icon is not attached when submitting to Appstore

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, app-store

I am about to submit an update to my game to Apple App Store and the display icon is not attached for some reason. When i run the simulator and device and press home scene it is there but when I validate the build it is not there.

[image]

I do have the graphics in the asset catalog "AppIcon-2", which have the correct sizes as well.

[image]

This is what i get after archiving the project to prepare to submit.

Anyone with some good ideas what i might do wrong here?

Comment: Have you deleted the original AppIcon asset?

Comment: No but i have a separate version for iPhone, that works, and one for iPad. This is due to historical reasons as when i initially launched this game you could not have universal.